# How do I set a URL to a custom record type depending on the custom taxonomies attached to it?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

**I created a Custom Post Type (Storages) /storage/:**

[Example in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59TPQ.png)

**Also attached to them Custom Taxonomies (Regions) /storage/us/new-york/:**

[Example in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hzX0.png)

Now, when adding any record, I generate a url of the following type **/storage/my-storage/**.

How to implement so that the hierarchy of taxonomies is observed and substituted in the url?

How to get this result: **/storage/us/new-york/my-storage** or **/storage/us/my-storage**

Comment: I for one use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Answer (score 1):

All my problems were solved by the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-better-permalinks/